# Why only std::atomic_flag is guaranteed to be lock-free?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, lock-free, stdatomic

From C++ Concurrency in Action:

> difference between std::atomic and std::atomic_flag is that std::atomic may not be lock-free; the implementation may have to acquire a mutex internally in order to ensure the atomicity of the operations

I wonder why. If atomic_flag is guaranteed to be lock-free, why isn't it guaranteed for `atomic<bool>` as well?
Is this because of the member function `compare_exchange_weak`? I know that some machines lack a single compare-and-exchange instruction, is that the reason?

Comment: Because `std::atomic<T>` has a type argument, std::atomic_flag does not.  Whether T updates are atomic depends on the processor architecture.  The library writer can pick any suitable type for atomic_flag.

Comment: Okay.
However my question is rather about this essential difference between  `std::atomic<bool>` and `std::atomic_flag`

Comment: I think no difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you are perfectly allowed to have something like `std::atomic<very_nontrivial_large_structure>`, so `std::atomic` as such cannot generally be guaranteed to be lock-free (although most specializations for trivial types like `bool` or `int` probably could, on most systems). But that is somewhat unrelated.

The exact reasoning why `atomic_flag` and nothing else **must be** lock-free is given in the Note in N2427/29.3:

> Hence the operations must be address-free. No other type requires lock-free operations, and hence the atomic_flag type is **the minimum hardware-implemented type needed to conform** to this standard. **The remaining types can be emulated with atomic_flag**, though with less than ideal properties.

In other words, it's the minimum thing that must be guaranteed on every platform, so it's possible to implement the standard correctly.

Comment: Correctly and uselessly

Comment: @curiousguy : I wouldn't say that. On most platforms, all types (including compound types) smaller than 16 bytes are lockfree. On almost all, except some microcontrollers or 35 year old crapware, everything up to 8 bytes is. You can query your implementation if you need to know, but more importantly you can write code that **will work** regardless, and will work as fast as possible on most architectures. It's actually pretty cool.

Comment: Yes. "_you are perfectly allowed to have something like std::atomic<very_nontrivial_large_structure>_" You can, but it isn't very useful.

Comment: @curiousguy: Again, I wouldn't necessarily say that. There's situations where you have more than just one value (explict waiter count, for example), and you may want to compare-exchange one of them _or both_ at the same time, depending on what you do. So it's pretty nice that as long as size is below some two-pointer-sized magic constant, you can just do what you want, and it works. I wish there were something like cacheline-sized atomics (why not actually...). Now **that** would really be cool.

Comment: Yes but "where you have more than just one value", with one ptr and one use count, is not a very large structure. `very_nontrivial_large_structure` has a "size in the hundreds of bytes" connotation. Or may it's just me.

Answer (score 2):

The standard does not garantee atomic objects are lock-free. On a platform that doesn't provide lock-free atomic operations for a type `T`, `std::atomic<T>` objects may be implemented using a mutex, which wouldn't be lock-free. In that case, any containers using these objects in their implementation would not be lock-free either.

The standard provide an opportunity to check if an `std::atomic<T>` variable is lock-free: you can use `var.is_lock_free()` or `atomic_is_lock_free(&var)`. For basic types such as int, there is also macros provided (e.g. `ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE`) which specify if lock-free atomic access to that type is available.

`std::atomic_flag` is an atomic boolean type. Almost always for `boolean` type it's not needed to use mutex or another way for synchronization.